How to get supported locales from SPXSpeechRecognizer in Azure Speech SDK for Swift?
I'm working with the Azure Speech SDK for iOS in Swift, and I need to retrieve the list of supported locales for Speech-to-Text.
I've checked the documentation then I found an API
for this but I haven't found a way to retrieve the list of supported languages directly from the SDK in Swift.
I'm aware of how to do this with SPXSpeechSynthesizer by using the getVoices method.
Any guidance on how to achieve this in Swift would be greatly appreciated!
